# NSPredicate: unrecognized selector sent to instance when filtering array of NSDateComponents using filteredArrayUsingPredicate

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdate, nspredicate, nsdatecomponent

I have some code in which I'm getting an array of dates from now to one year

```
        NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        NSMutableArray *dateComponentsInRange = [NSMutableArray new];
        NSDate *curDate = [dates objectAtIndex:0];

        while ([curDate timeIntervalSince1970] <= [[dates lastObject] timeIntervalSince1970])
        {
            NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:curDate];
            [dateComponentsInRange addObject:components];
            curDate = [curDate dateWithNextDay];
        }
```

I need to filter that array(`dateComponentsInRange`) with another array of date components comparing by day, month, and year.

So far I tried this

```
        NSDateComponents *components = nil;
        NSMutableArray *predicates = [NSMutableArray array];;
        for (NSDate *currentdate in dates)
        {
            components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:currentdate];
            NSString *preficateFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(SELF.day  != %d AND SELF.month != %d AND SELF.year != %d)",[components day],[components month], [components year]];
            [predicates addObject:preficateFormat];
        }
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicates];
        NSArray *filteredArr = [dateComponentsInRange filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

But I'm getting the following error

```
 [__NSCFString evaluateWithObject:substitutionVariables:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Comment: Make sure you have no nil dates.

Comment: You missed the important part of the error message. What does the rest of it say?

Comment: There are no nil dates in the array I even tried with just one non nil element in the array and still getting that error

Comment: That's all the message I'm getting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding a string to an array and using it as a predicate.

Try:

```
    NSDateComponents *components = nil;
    NSMutableArray *predicates = [NSMutableArray array];;
    for (NSDate *currentdate in dates)
    {
        components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:currentdate];
        NSString *preficateFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(SELF.day  != %d AND SELF.month != %d AND SELF.year != %d)",[components day],[components month], [components year]];
        NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:preficateFormat];
        [predicates addObject:predicate];
    }
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicates];
    NSArray *filteredArr = [dateComponentsInRange filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple Docs `orPredicateWithSubpredicates` expects an array of `NSPredicate` but you're passing an array of `NSString` objects.

The error says

> > `[__NSCFString evaluateWithObject:substitutionVariables:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

which is correct since `evaluateWithObject:substitutionVariables` is not defined for `NSString` but for `NSPredicate`

Src: Apple Documentation